# execute serverless deploy with aws role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy a simple lambda funtcion with the serverless framework. My IAM user doesn't have the necessary permissions to run cloudformation:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/xxx is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:xxx:stack/xx
```

That's more or less intended, since our setup is using IAM roles to perform certain tasks. I have configured those roles in my ~/.aws/config
file, and for aws cli operations I can e.g. call

```
aws s3 ls --profile myrole
```

in that way I attach all policies from the role 'myrole' to my IAM user to execute the aws-cli command.

Is there any way of doing something similar for serverless, i.e. attaching a role (not a different user) to the

```
serverless depoly
```

statement?

If I change the role via export

`AWS_PROFILE=myrole`

or call

`serverless deploy --aws-profile myrole`

I get `Error: Profile myrole does not exist` even though the role is defined in  `/.aws/credentials` and  `~/.aws/config`

Comment: You will need one IAM user or role with all the permissions needed todo the deployment.

Comment: Thanks @WaltDe but how cal I attach that role to my deployment command?

Comment: You will need assume your deployment role before running serverless which you can do through the environment variable AWS_PROFILE  For details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html#cli-role-prepare

Comment: no success, I get `Error: Profile myrole does not exist` . I just found a similar issue described here: [https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5474]

Answer (score 21):

OK, I found a solution to get this working. Apparently you need to set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG to a truthy value, such that the Session will be created from the configuration values from the shared config (~/.aws/config) and shared credentials (~/.aws/credentials) files.

```
export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

then execute with

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile myrole
```

Comment: yes, yes, yes! I was fighting with policies and roles and the problem was within environmental variable. Stefan, you made my day. Thank you!

Comment: Can you get that to work for EKS with a pod running in a fargate profile?

Comment: Thx for saving 2h of my times dude ;)