# AWS profile doesn't seem to be configured! Serverless framework error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

**Background:-**I have a gateway account( with no permissions) in which users are created and in order to access aws resources we use roles having admin access.

**config file**

```
[profile gateway]
region = ap-southeast-1
output = json

[profile DA]

region = ap-south-1
output = json
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/jatin
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:mfa/atin
source_profile = gateway
```

credentials file

```
[gateway]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now I am trying to deploy my lambda using serverless deploy --aws-profile "DA", it says `AWS profile "DA" doesn't seem to be configured`

however, if I run `aws s3 ls --profile "DA"` its works perfectly, so i guess there is no problem with the configuration of profiles and credentials

Comment: I'm confused, when I look at your config and credentials file I see a profile called `gateway` but you mention `DA`. Where is the profile `DA` configured? In the config the block headed by `region = ap-south-1` is not headed by a `[profile ...]`, is this intentional?

Comment: sorry i did the mistake in my block, i have edited that please check once

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a known issue with Serverless, Serverless only checks `~/.aws/credentials` for the profile and not `~/.aws/config`.

There are multiple Serverless forum posts about this, [e.g. this one](https://forum.serverless.com/t/sample-serverless-yml-for-multiple-aws-accounts-needed/1528/12).

Change your `~/.aws/credentials` file to this and it should work:

```
[gateway]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[DA]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/jatin
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:mfa/atin
source_profile = gateway
```

Comment: thank you for your help, much appreciated but i can not generate programmatic keys for DA role because the idea  that request should go to gateway account and then using role work should be done as a security practice

Comment: However yesterday i tried this `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`
then execute 
`serverless deploy --aws-profile myrole` somehow it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/57707059/13126651
but i am not satisfied with explanation as to why this worked can @yvesonline look into this?

Comment: The idea was that you copy & paste the keys from `gateway` to the `DA` role. As for the `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` approach, it kind of makes sense, it basically bypasses `credentials` and goes straight to `config` which was the problem Serverless had in the first place. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html#setting-region-config-file) explains it a bit better.

Comment: I tried your answer but the error is the same

Comment: Then I'd go with the `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` approach, the forum entry post I linked reported about a lot of difficulties and issues, so if you've found something that's working for you then good. Happy to update the answer.

Comment: thank you for the efforts much appreciated.

Answer (score 27):

A better solution is to specify `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` without messing with your credentials:
`AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 sls deploy`

Make sure you have the `serverless-better-credentials` serverless plugin installed, as it's needed for this to work. Follow installation instructions at https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-better-credentials

Comment: Doesn't even remotely work, same error

Comment: perfect, works.

Comment: Make sure you have the `serverless-better-credentials` serverless plugin installed, as it's needed for this to work. Follow installation instructions at https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-better-credential

Comment: @DanielSandoval The correct link is https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-better-credentials

Comment: @Sandoval weird, I never had that plugin. Did they change it lately?