# AWS SDK Missing credentials in config

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cli

**Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1**

I am using "aws-sdk": "^2.918.0" in a react native (0.64.0) project. I am running the program using node v14.17.0 and on a Windows 10 version 21H1 OS build 19043.985:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  maxRetries: 3,
  httpOptions: {timeout: 30000, connectTimeout: 5000},
});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
});

console.log('ddb: ', ddb);
```

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
output=json

[profile myName]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXX...
aws_secret_access_key=XXX...

[mateo\.lara]
aws_access_key_id=XXX...
aws_secret_access_key=XXX...
```

[image: configuration data]

When using ddb to query the database, I am getting this CredentialsError, despite having configured my credential in AWS CLI (aws-cli/2.2.6 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off). Do you know what the problem could be? And how to solve it?

-------------------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------------

As suggested by @nishkaush I have tried adding AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 to the config file, and I have tried deleting the credential file and adding aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key to the config file without success.

Here is the output of the ddb log:

```
ddb:  {"CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE": [Function CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE], "MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE": [Function EVENTS_BUBBLE], "_clientId": 1, "_events": {"apiCall": [[Function CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE]], "apiCallAttempt": [[Function EVENTS_BUBBLE]]}, "config": {"apiVersion": "2012-08-10", "apiVersions": {}, "clientSideMonitoring": 
false, "computeChecksums": true, "convertResponseTypes": true, "correctClockSkew": false, "credentialProvider": null, "credentials": null, "customUserAgent": null, "dynamoDbCrc32": true, "endpoint": "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "endpointCacheSize": 1000, "endpointDiscoveryEnabled": undefined, "hostPrefixEnabled": true, "httpOptions": {"connectTimeout": 5000, "timeout": 30000}, "logger": null, "maxRedirects": 10, "maxRetries": 3, "paramValidation": true, "region": "us-east-1", "retryDelayOptions": {}, "s3BucketEndpoint": false, "s3DisableBodySigning": true, "s3ForcePathStyle": false, "s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint": "legacy", 
"s3UseArnRegion": undefined, "signatureCache": true, "signatureVersion": "v4", "sslEnabled": true, "stsRegionalEndpoints": "legacy", "systemClockOffset": 0, "useAccelerateEndpoint": false}, "endpoint": {"host": "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "hostname": "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "href": "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/", "path": "/", "pathname": "/", "port": 443, "protocol": "https:"}, "isGlobalEndpoint": false}
```

Comment: i had a similar problem, would you mind checking this question and its answer and comment, may it can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66560150/13126651

Comment: As suggested I add the IAM role of DynamoDB table in the profile in ~/.aws/credentials but the error persists.

Comment: Can you try this command in your terminal and then try running your node.js code `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` and if error still persist try adding your keys within your code lime this `aws.config.update({
    region: "eu-west-1",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8080",
    accessKeyId: “xxxxxx”,
    secretAccessKey: “xxxxxx”
});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, thank nishkaush and Jatin Mehrotra for their help. In the end, the only way I could solve my problem was by adding the 'accessKeyId' and 'secretAccessKey' directly to my AWS.config.update. This is not by any means a final solution, and you should avoid putting the credentials directly to your code (security reasons). Be aware that if you intend to use this solution, you should set your credentials through a .env file and add it to a gitignore to protect your credentials. I would have liked to configure my credentials using the shared credentials file, but I am running out of time, and the problem persists. If it is of any help, please check:

[AWS Getting Started in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html)

[AWS Loading Credentials in Node.js from the Shared Credentials File](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

Having said that, the problem may be related to the fact that I am working with react native, anyway here is the solution:

```
AWS.config.update({
  maxRetries: 3,
  httpOptions: {timeout: 30000, connectTimeout: 5000},
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXX...',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXX...',
});
```

Comment: is timeout working fine in android ??

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.aws/config` file, could you try setting this as well:

```sh
..
..
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

Alternatively, you can try deleting `~/.aws/credentials` file and move both `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` to `~/.aws/config` file instead, something like so:

```sh
[default]
region=us-east-1
output=json
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXX
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, the change you proposed did not solve the problem: Same error message  (CredentialsError) after adding AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 to both profiles in the config file.

Comment: can you try deleting `~/.aws/credentials file` and move both `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` to `~/.aws/config` file instead. I have also added this same info to my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set

```
s3.config.s3UseArnRegion = true;
```

condition if you get error related to s3UseArnRegion undefined

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused due to incorrect credentials. My `identityPoolID` value was erroneously stored as `undefined` due to a parsing error.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, I resolved it by

1. Add `credentials` in the file `~/.aws/credentials`.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXX
```

2. Add `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` in the file `~/.aws/config`.

```
[default]
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```